# How to manage Ubuntu time?

Tags: time, ntp

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

I was reading about [Ubuntu Time Management](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime).

Instructions on that page describe the need to go into the Administration sub-menu and click on Time and Date.
The Time and Date menus I have don't look anything like the ones on the web page.
Plus I understand the Administration page has been removed.

Are there updated instructions for Time Management on Ubuntu 16.04?

I see the tag where it says "Needs Updating."
For what version of Ubuntu was this written?

Ultimately, I would like to exercise Time Synchronization using NTP.
Are there updated instructions for NTP Management on Ubuntu 16.04?

I searched for "Time Synchronization using NTP on Ubuntu 16.04" on AskUbuntu.
I get only 1 result: a question that was never answered.

Comment: Have you tried to use *timedatectl* command to fix your issue? Comment if you still need help?